# if one object fails all objects rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    installations.each do |installation|
      id = installation.id
      installation = current_user.installations.find_by(:id=> id)
      @ticket = installation.tickets.new(ticket_params)
      unless @ticket.save
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  end
  redirect_to '/tickets', notice: "done"
rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
  render action: "new", notice: "problem" and return
end
```

Imagine that we have two tickets, the first ticket is valid and the second is invalid. In this code the first ticket will be saved. But I want to rollback all the tickets when one fail.
How can I do that ?

Comment: How is that not working?

Comment: Although your code can be shortened, it should work just fine.

Comment: The problem in this code is that the first ticket is saved! I want to rollback the two tickets @ndn

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I believe this is a property of the ActiveRecord::Rollback exception.. It doesn't behave like other exceptions and will only rollback the one failure instead of the whole transaction. If instead of the unless block you do an @ticket.save!, the '!' will throw an exception (not Rollback) that will discard the entire transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a collection of `@ticket.save`'s return values, call `.all?` on them, and if you get a false raise the rollback:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  installations.each do |installation|
    tickets_saved = []
    id = installation.id
    installation = current_user.installations.find_by(:id=> id)
    ticket = installation.tickets.new(ticket_params)
    tickets_saved << ticket.save
  end

  unless tickets_saved.all?
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Comment: This does the same thing as the original code, except that it will still try to save the remaining valid tickets after it found an invalid one.

Comment: ...Yep, my bad :)